# How to choose the correct version of the .NET framework selected in the ASP.NET tab (in IIS) for web application?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am new to creating web applications in ASP.net. I am trying to create simple web service calculator, that adds two numbers. But when I invoke, it gives me an error:

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /CalculatorWebService.asmx/Add
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1073.0
```

In order to fix it I want to make sure I have the correct version of the .NET framework selected in the ASP.NET tab (in IIS) for this application. So, I am going to IIS manager--> View Application Pools and this is what I see:
[image]

Am I on a right way?
Which one should I choose?

what am I doing wrong? according to youtube video that what I've done:
[image]

here is my code in VS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyWebApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CalculatorWebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://calculatorwebservice.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class CalculatorWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public int Add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
        {
            return firstNumber+secondNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't look a that yet. Your app folder is not bound in IIS. In other words you have to create an application in IIS, specify the sub-url (http://localhost/myapp) and path to physical dir with the files.

Comment: are there any examples of doing that?

Comment: And more thing. Your best shot is version 4.0.... (there are two to choose 2.0 and 4.0) and Integrated pipline, most of the time.